# Magento 2 Country Name not get translated when using countryFactory

Tags: magento2, locale, countries

My Magento site have about 10 different websites and one for each country. I have set the correct `Locale` corresponding to each country (storeview).

I'm getting **Country Name** by using `countryFactory`, the problem is, when switching **Storeview**, it doesn't get me the country name translated according to the `Locale` i configured in the admin.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
    )
    {
        $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    }

    public function getCountryName($code)
    {
        $_country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($code);
        if($_country)
        {
            return $_country->getName();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

How do I get country name translated when switching the storeview?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use locale code as param in getName

```
<?php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory
) {
    $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
}

public function getCountryName($code)
{
    $_country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($code);
    if($_country) {
        return $_country->getName('Your locale code');
    }

    return false;
}
```

Example:

```
<?php
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory $countryFactory,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
)
{
    $this->countryFactory = $countryFactory;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function getCountryName($code)
{
    $_country = $this->countryFactory->create()->loadByCode($code);
    if($_country) {
        /* current store id */
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        return $_country->getName($this->getStoreLocale($storeId));
    }

    return false;
}

private function getStoreLocale($storeId)
{
    $locale = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface:: SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    return $locale;
}
```

Comment: Great, it's working. thanks

Comment: Welcome @MagentoLearner